# Extract part of a line from a string

Tags: ruby, string

I have a string in Ruby like this:

```
var = <<EOS

***************************
Test Spec:  somespecname 
Test Case:  get new status
EOS
```

I want to retrieve the name following the `"Test Spec:"` part of the string. So in this case I want the result to be  `"somespecname"`.

How can I do it in Ruby?

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

```
var.match(/Spec:\s*(\w+)/)[1] # => "somespecname"
```

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the OP's example, I assume that there are cases when the string to be retrieved may include non-word characters. This regex will capture them correctly as well.

```
var.match(/^Test Spec:\s*(.*?)\s*$/)[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`String#[]`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) and [`String#strip`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/String.html#method-i-strip) methods:

```
var[/Test Spec:(.*)$/, 1].strip
# => "somespecname"
```

**Update**: An alternative expression using lookbehind:

```
var[/(?<=Test Spec:).*$/].strip
```

Comment: This regex looks very similar to mine.

Answer (score 1):

You can divide the string into array elements using split for easier reference than regex or match.

```
  var = "\n\n\nTest Spec:  somespecname \nTest Case:  get new status"

  var.strip! 
  # => "Test Spec:  somespecname \nTest Case:  get new status" 
  new_var = var.split("\n")
  # => ["Test Spec:  somespecname ", "Test Case:  get new status"]
  test_spec_element = new_var[0]
  # => "Test Spec:  somespecname "
  desired_string = test_spec_element.split(":")[0]
  # => " somespecname "
```

Comment: After reading your answer I've realized I've edited the question in quite a bad way before, the original string posted by OP has more lines. I've restored the original string, you may want to edit your answer accordingly, sorry for the inconvenient.